# Devise Routing Error on Gem Update (Rails 3, Devise + Omniauth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes, omniauth

I am using Devise + Omniauth (Facebook) and recently updated my gems (Rails 3.0.5, Ruby 1.9.2). Upon starting my app server the following line in routes.rb:

> devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "registrations" }

has begun raising the following error:

```
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:62:in `add_route': conditions may only include [:auth_type, :gateway_interface, :path_translated, :remote_host, :remote_ident, :remote_user, :remote_addr, :server_name, :server_protocol, :accept, :accept_charset, :accept_encoding, :accept_language, :cache_control, :from, :negotiate, :pragma, :key?, :request_method, :request_method_symbol, :method, :method_symbol, :get?, :post?, :put?, :delete?, :head?, :headers, :fullpath, :forgery_whitelisted?, :forgery_whitelisted_with_deprecation?, :forgery_whitelisted_without_deprecation?, :media_type, :content_length, :xml_http_request?, :xhr?, :ip, :remote_ip, :server_software, :raw_post, :body, :form_data?, :body_stream, :reset_session, :session=, :session_options=, :GET, :query_parameters, :POST, :request_parameters, :authorization, :local?, :cookie_jar, :flash, :url, :scheme, :protocol, :ssl?, :raw_host_with_port, :host, :host_with_port, :port, :standard_port, :standard_port?, :port_string, :server_port, :domain, :subdomains, :subdomain, :request_uri, :filtered_parameters, :filtered_env, :parameters, :params, :path_parameters=, :symbolized_path_parameters, :path_parameters, :content_mime_type, :content_type, :accepts, :format, :formats, :format=, :negotiate_mime, :if_modified_since, :if_none_match, :not_modified?, :etag_matches?, :fresh?, :env, :script_name, :path_info, :query_string, :session, :session_options, :logger, :media_type_params, :content_charset, :script_name=, :path_info=, :options?, :trace?, :parseable_data?, :[], :[]=, :values_at, :referer, :referrer, :user_agent, :cookies, :path, :location, :taguri=, :taguri, :to_yaml_style, :to_yaml_properties, :syck_to_yaml, :to_yaml, :blank?, :present?, :presence, :duplicable?, :acts_like?, :try, :html_safe?, :to_json, :instance_values, :instance_variable_names, :copy_instance_variables_from, :as_json, :with_options, :to_param, :to_query, :friendly_id?, :unfriendly_id?, :to_html, :dclone, :`, :returning, :require_or_load, :require_dependency, :require_association, :load_dependency, :load, :require, :unloadable, :nil?, :===, :=~, :!~, :eql?, :hash, :<=>, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :initialize_dup, :initialize_clone, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :freeze, :frozen?, :to_s, :inspect, :methods, :singleton_methods, :protected_methods, :private_methods, :public_methods, :instance_variables, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, :instance_variable_defined?, :instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :send, :public_send, :respond_to?, :respond_to_missing?, :extend, :display, :public_method, :define_singleton_method, :__id__, :object_id, :to_enum, :enum_for, :gem, :silence_warnings, :enable_warnings, :with_warnings, :silence_stderr, :silence_stream, :suppress, :class_eval, :suppress_warnings, :require_library_or_gem, :debugger, :breakpoint, :==, :equal?, :!, :!=, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :__send__] (ArgumentError)
```

Is there a new a syntax for routes named in this way?

Comment: i've temporarily solved this by reverting back to rails 3.0.3

Comment: I am currently experiencing this on 3.0.7.  Just a note for anyone trying to diagnose:  I get this error when the model is :omniauthable even if there are no additional options passed to do devise_for :users

Answer (score 1):

You can hack it by changing line 338 in devise-1.4.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb to:

```
match "#{path_prefix}/:action/callback", #:action => Regexp.union(mapping.to.omniauth_providers.map(&:to_s)),
```

Be warned that this is only an ugly hack not a final solution to the problem!

Make sure you have set

```
devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:twitter]
```

in your devise model (e.g. User).

Comment: @norm do you have a workaround for this, is it not patched in a more recent Devise?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to forgery-0.4.0 if you're using it with with Devise/Omniauth. We were extending some base ruby classes (always a great idea, I know) and this somehow caused issues in Devise. Version 0.4.0 no longer extends any ruby base classes and should be completely safe to include. Let us know if you have any issues at http://github.com/sevenwire/forgery. Thanks!